# Which is the prime module for creating a form in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

What is the best module to use for Drupal? I just go through Web forms and also Entity forms modules. As with everything in Drupal, there are Pros and Cons to using these modules also, so I was just wondering when to use these modules?

Anybody have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

*Entityforms* have some problems with translation. But they have more options since they are ENTITIES (can have fields, permissions, views integration etc). In my opionion, they are the future.

*Webforms*, otherhand, are widely used. They also have some problems with translations but they have so much additional helper modules around it. And they may be better for Surveys.

So it depends on the task.

**See more at related documentation: [When to use Entityforms](https://drupal.org/node/1540680)**.